# "'Mega' object has no attribute 'get_name_from_file'" when writing files to Mega

Tags: deja-dup, duplicity

I am trying to have deja-dup backup my system to my https://mega.co.nz account

1- Déjà dup = Ubuntu easy front end to the powerful Duplicity
2- Duplicity states it supports Mega as from version v0.6.23 (through a mega:// URI)

**---Using Duplicity v0.6.23----**

The command

```
duplicity /test mega://myemail%40yahoo.com:mypassword@mega.co.nz/test
```

successfully writes files in my Mega directory but it displays the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1489, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1483, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1332, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1361, in do_backup
    sync_archive(decrypt)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1094, in sync_archive
    remlist = globals.backend.list()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 429, in list
    return map(tobytes, self._list())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 330, in iterate
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/megabackend.py", line 115, in _list
    % (self.__get_node_name(self.folder), str(e)), raise_errors)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/megabackend.py", line 139, in __get_node_name
    return self.client.get_name_from_file({handle:files[handle]})
AttributeError: 'Mega' object has no attribute 'get_name_from_file'
```

**---Using Déjà Dup 30.0----**

In the "Storage" tab, I select

- Backup location: Custom Location
- URI: mega://myemail%40yahoo.com:mypassword@mega.co.nz/test

but it produces the error "Backup Failed: Location is not mountable"

**Do you know any solution to use Déjà Dup (or Duplicity without errors) to create an easy backup solution to mega.co.nz?**

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

This is one of those [wisdom of the ancients](https://xkcd.com/979/) sorts of situations.

So, ummm...

Dear people of the future, here's what we've figured out so far:

It seems the code for the Python module has been deprecated. There's a link on the page that says there's something newer, but that link 404s.

I'm using Debian Jessie, but I'm assuming it should be similar for Ubuntu. You need to edit the file `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mega/mega.py` as root in whatever text editor you use. Then add the following code just under `class Mega(object):`:

```python
def get_name_from_file(self, file):
    for key, value in file.items():
        if 'a' in value and 'n' in value['a']:
             return value['a']['n']
    raise RequestError("Could not find the file attribute.")
```

It seems to make it so duplicity can actually restore the files that it backs up on Mega... which might be a bit important if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Mega directly via duplicity successfully.  I remember I had to grab a git checkout of the mega python module and even then had to fix a couple bugs with it.  But I don't remember that particular error.  So maybe the mega python module is just a little janky.

As for the Deja Dup "custom location" box, that is for GNOME urls like you would put in the File Browser location bar, not for duplicity urls.

Right now, Deja Dup does not support Mega as a destination.  Sorry.  :(

Comment: MEGA is supported by Duplicity as from v0.6.23 so I understand the git recipe you are talking about (https://code.launchpad.net/~ckornacker/duplicity/megacloud) has been integrated as standard. Do you have an idea on how to fix the errors mentioned here above?

Comment: About Deja-Dup, I just realized there is a git recipe also from Christian Kornacker (https://code.launchpad.net/~ckornacker/deja-dup/megacloud) but it is only available for Deja-Dup 26 on Ubuntu Saucy (13.10) or Raring (13.04). Maybe it is not included in the latest version of Deja-Dup because of the licensing problem mentioned here: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/29312/deja-dup-backups-to-megaconz/ (http://megatools.megous.com/) ?